# Trying to upsert document in flask_MongoEngine

Tags: mongoengine, upsert, flask-mongoengine

I've currently got a model:

```
class Ticket(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField #issue.key
    project = db.StringField() #issue.fields.project.key
    issue_type = db.StringField() #issue.fields.issuetype.name
    summary = db.StringField() #issue.fields.summary
    description = db.StringField() #issue.fields.description
    created = db.DateTimeField() #issue.fields.created
    updated = db.DateTimeField() #issue.fields.updated
```

And some code that attempts to upsert:

```
Ticket.objects(name=name).update(
        upsert = True,
        name = name,
        project = project,
        issue_type = issue_type,
        summary = summary,
        description = description,
        created = created,
        updated = updated
    )
```

And I'm getting this error message:

```
mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "name"
```

With the relevant bit saying the error occurs in

```
updated = updated
```

So far I've tried re-naming the fields of my variables and my model, but the error message remains the same. Sorry for asking if there's an in my face answer I'm blind to.

Update: If I delete name = name from the update it works fine. I renamed name to title and re-added it and it does not work. I am thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a moron and left off parens on name in the model.